# How to dynamically choose columns in flextable package in R

Tags: r, flextable

I have the following table created using the `flextable` package in R.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)

data <- structure(list(Category = structure(1:2, levels = c("Baseline", 
"Alternate"), class = "factor"), `2022 Q2` = c("6%", "6.4%"), 
    `2022 Q3` = c("6.5%", "6.7%"), `2022 Q4` = c("6.4%", "6.6%"
    ), `2023 Q1` = c("5.7%", "5.5%"), `2023 Q2` = c("4.5%", "4.8%"
    ), `2023 Q3` = c("4.2%", "4.7%"), `2023 Q4` = c("4%", "4.6%"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

data %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  align(j = 2:8, align = "center")
```

Instead of manually choosing which columns to align (`j = 2:8` in this case), I would like to dynamically select all the columns from the second to the last column. I have tried `align(j = 2:n(), align = "center")` similar to how I would do it in `dplyr`, however that isn't possible in `flextable` notation. Any suggestions?

Comment: you mean `j=2:ncol(data)` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ncol()` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)


data %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  align(j = 2:ncol(data), align = "center")
```

**EDIT** And thanks to the comment by @DavidGohel a second and preferable solution would be to use `flextable::ncol_keys`. The last option has the benefit that it also works in cases where only some data columns will be displayed in the flextable.

```
data %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  align(j = 2:ncol_keys(.), align = "center")
```

[image]

Comment: Another solution could be to use `2:ncol_keys(.)` as sometimes flextable don't show all original columns but use fake columns or simply don't display all original columns

Comment: Thx@DavidGohel for pointing that out. Already guessed that `flextable` offers a convenience function for this task.